# Store multiple rows from mysql database into one single variable

Tags: php, mysql

this is really hard for me, i'm trying to store multiple rows from my table in mysql into a single variable

---

```
$mysql_statementJc = "SELECT * FROM `dog`.`cat` WHERE `name` = '$name'";
$mysql_commandJc = mysql_query($mysql_statementJc);


 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_commandJc)){

    $followI = $row['industry'];

    $groupConcat = $followI . " OR ";

    echo $groupConcat;
}
```

---

This is my appproach, so at the end of it all i can get "sam, john, bob" saved as $groupConcat which can then be used elsewhere.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to store them in an array variable? What have you tried already and what error are you encountering?

Comment: I have tried concatenating all of the variable in the while loop and that won't work, i don't know if arrays will work best as when i get the name e.g john i want to seperate it and put a OR in e.g "john OR sam OR dylan" which would be stored as a variable

Comment: What if you put a dot before the equal sign like this: `$groupConcat .= $followI . " OR ";` Also, move the echo after the while block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time through the loop, add the desired value to an array.  Then, after the loop, use the [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to create your desired output.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_commandJc)){

    $followI = $row['industry'];

    $resultArray[] = $followI;
}

$groupConcat = implode(" OR ", $resultArray);

echo $groupConcat;
```

Note that you should really stop using the mysql library and instead use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 3):

you want to create a concatenated string, php has the  `.=` syntax for this:

```
$groupConcat='';

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_commandJc)){
    $groupConcat .= $row['industry'] . " OR ";
}
    echo $groupConcat; //no point echoing inside the loop
```

sometimes a better approach is to use an array and `implode()`

```
$groupConcat=array();

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_commandJc)){
    $groupConcat[] = $row['industry'];
}
    echo implode(' OR ',$groupConcat);
```

Comment: In ist solution OP will get the OR on end in last iteration . second solution is best one

Comment: trivial to remove the extra OR

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it as:

```
$followl = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_commandJc))
{ 
    $followl[] = $row['industry'];
}

$groupConcat = implode(" OR ",$followl);
echo $groupConcat;
```

**Some Explanation**:

Store values into an array `$followl` and than use `implode()` function for imploding with **OR**.

**Side note**:

Please use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` becuase `mysql_*` is deprecated and no more available in PHP 7.

Comment: `$followl` vs `$followI`